# How to open a URL in a new browser window with AutoHotkey?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

With [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) on Windows you can associate a shortcut to open a URL - *web page or link* - in the default browser with the following script:

```
^!g::Run https://mail.google.com/
```

This will open Gmail **in a new tab** in the last active window when pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

How can I do same, but open the URL **in a new window** instead?

Comment: You need to pass the appropriate command line switch for your default browser.

Comment: What is your browser?

Comment: @harrymc Chrome, but I what I was actually looking for is a general solution which would work with any browser

Comment: it depends on the browser to choose to open a link in a new tab or new window, so obviously there's no general solution. Either you pass a command line option, or set some permanent browser settings

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**IE**:

```
Run, iexplore.exe https://mail.google.com/
```

**Chrome**:

```
Run, chrome.exe "https://mail.google.com/" " --new-window "
```

**Firefox**:

```
Run, firefox.exe -new-window https://mail.google.com/
```

**Microsoft Edge**:

```
Run, msedge.exe "https://mail.google.com/" " --new-window"
```

Comment: If I want to use multiple options like " --new-window --profile-directory=""Profile 1""" I couldn't get them both to work

Answer (score 1):

In AutoHotkey v2 Alpha

Google Chrome

```
Run "chrome.exe https://www.google.com --new-window "
```

Firefox :

```
Run "firefox.exe " "-new-window www.google.com/"
```

Microsoft Edge (Chrome Core)

```
Run "msedge.exe www.google.com/ --new-window"
```

Answer (score 0):

Autohotkey, open an URL in the default-browser
using a temporary local file.

```
 ; Autohotkey, open an URL in the default-browser,
 ; a "little dirty" trick

; first opening a temporary local file with browser
; (the one which is registered to open local html-files)
; this file contains the javascript command "document.location.href"
; to open the url

url := "https://superuser.com/questions/1410878/how-to-open-a-url-in-a-new-browser-window-with-autohotkey"

; a temporary file, running directory must be writeable
outputFile := "a$$$$$$.html"
if (FileExist(outputFile))
    FileDelete, %outputFile%

FileAppend,
(
<html>
<body>
<script>
document.location.href="
),%outputFile%
FileAppend,%url%,%outputFile%
FileAppend,
(
"
</script>
</body>
</html>
),%outputFile%

cmdToRun := "cmd /c " . outputFile
run, %cmdToRun%

sleep,5000

; remove temporary file
if (FileExist(outputFile))
    FileDelete, %outputFile%
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).